# Debugging Windows Form Thread Freezes

Tags: c#, debugging, com

I have a C# winforms application, which communicates to various com data sources, and uses a threadpool for most of its backend processing. I have noticed that 2-3 times a day the winforms thread hangs for 20-30 seconds (visible in the ui, and that the com data stops for 20-30 secs). I have since written a simple task on the threadpool that tracks a heartbeat on the winforms thread to detect these instances, but am looking for a way to automatically trigger a full dump (not a mini dump), so that I can see what exactly the winforms thread is doing during these pauses.

Are there any simple command line apps that my background thread can call on it's own process to bind to the app as a debugger, generate the full dump file, and then allow the application to resume?

Is there a better way to debug this?

Comment: Delays like this are likely caused by a full garbage collection.  With either gcServer enabled or the app exhausting the ability of concurrent/background GC to keep up.  Threads will be blocked, including your watchdog thread unless you manage to make it not allocate any GC memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SysInternals [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) utility to generate dump files:

> ProcDump is a command-line utility
>   whose primary purpose is monitoring an
>   application for CPU spikes and
>   generating crash dumps during a spike
>   that an administrator or developer can
>   use to determine the cause of the
>   spike.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=E089CA41-6A87-40C8-BF69-28AC08570B7E&displaylang=en) should do the trick.

Comment: Excellent tool - but it won't install on Win 7 - any similar tool for later os?